# Dynamic method return type based on variable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

I have a class called Collection that implements EKEnumerable that holds an array/enumrator and multiple subclasses called CarCollection, DriverCollection, etc. Collection has a variety of methods on it that currently return id or implement blocks that provide arguments typed as id. I would like to have Car, Driver, and other subclasses to be able to type the returns as well as the block arguments.

As an example in Collection:

```
- (id)find:(BOOL (^)(id))block
{
    id next;
    EKEnumerator *e = self.asEnumerator;
    while ((next = e.next)) {
        if (block(next)) {
            return next;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Would love for, in the CarCollection to be dynamically typed, instead of having to-implement every method in subclasses:

```
- (Car *)find:(BOOL (^)(Car *))block
{
    id next;
    EKEnumerator *e = self.asEnumerator;
    while ((next = e.next)) {
        if (block(next)) {
            return next;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Is this possible with metaprogramming, or will I need to re-implement every method with the correct type in each subclass.

Comment: Do you mean `instancetype`?

Comment: instancetype would return the type of the subclass, in this case CarCollection - I would like for the return type of methods such as find:, etc that return a single model from the collection to dynamically typed aka: find: on CarCollection would have a return type of Car * where as find: on DriverCollection would have a return type of Driver *, but I would like to do this without having to re-implement every single method in every subclass.